# Restrictions.eq with a list

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have a class called Product. Each Product has a serial_number. I want to return all products that have a serial_number that's in a list. Something like

```
Restrictions.eq("serial_number", mySerialNumberList);
```

Can that be done concisely, or do I have to build a huge query with lots of 'OR' properties thrown in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what the `IN` operator is for:

```
Restrictions.in("serialNumber", mySerialNumberList);
```

Be careful though: passing an empty list will result in a SQL grammar exception.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice that in the API.